# How do I properly encapsulate methods in sub-modules in Ruby? My methods won't appear anywhere!

Tags: ruby, module, methods

I've written a very basic *finance* module in Ruby to ease my own calculations, as sometimes it's just a lot easier to enter `irb` and start calling functions.  But the odd thing is, that in my module I have a submodule with a method called future_value (`Finance::CompoundInterest.future_value`) ... but according to `irb` it doesn't exist?  It's quite small, but I'd really prefer to be able to use compound interest instead of having to enter the formula each time.

When loading in `irb` no errors or warnings are thrown, and the method is invisible for all intents and purposes.  Almost sadly, I *can* instantiate a `Finance::Mortgage`.

Here's my finance unit:

```
module Finance
  module CompoundInterest
    def future_value(present_value, interest, length)
      interest /= 100 if interest >= 1 # if given in percent 1..100
      present_value * ((1 + interest)**length)
    end
  end

  class Mortgage
    attr_accessor :amount, :rate, :years, :payment, :interest_paid
    def initialize(amount, rate, years)
      @amount, @rate, @years = amount, rate, years

      i = rate  / 12
      n = years * 12
      m = (1 + i)**n

      @payment = ((i * m) / (m - 1)) * amount
      @interest_paid = @payment * n - amount
    end
  end
end
```

What have I mistyped to get this strange situation?  I am using Ruby 1.8.7-72.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the method declaration you need to prefix the name with "self." or with the name of the module i.e.

```
def self.future_value(present_value, interest, length)
```

or

```
def CompoundInterest.future_value(present_value, interest, length)
```

It should then work as you expect. This is the same way that you define a class method (as opposed to an instance method) on a class.

Comment: So to wit, just writing "def some_method" in a module defines a module instance method -- it's copied as an instance method into a class when you write "include SomeModule".

Comment: Oh!  I hadn't considered that.  Do the class-methods get implemented as such when included?

Comment: No, the self methods from the module don't get mixed in as class methods when included. Take a look at the "included" hook and the Class.extend method if this is something you'd like to do. Feel free to ask if you'd like more info.

Comment: You could also add `extend self` at the top of the module definition to make all instance methods available as class methods. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733124/ruby-extend-self