# Ruby: extend self

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, I understand the basic idea of `extend`. However, what's happening in this segment of code? Specifically, what does `extend` do? Is it just a convenient way of making the instance methods into class methods? Why would you do it this way rather than specifying class methods from the beginning?

```
module Rake
  include Test::Unit::Assertions

  def run_tests # etc.
  end

  # what does the next line do?
  extend self
end
```

Answer (score 121, accepted):

It is a convenient way to make instance methods into class methods. But you can also use it as a [more efficient singleton](https://web.archive.org/web/20180727051657/http://ozmm.org/posts/singin_singletons.html).

Comment: Why is that kind of singleton more efficient?

Comment: Your link has rotten my friend.

Comment: Updated this answer with a link to archive.org

Comment: This answer is inadequate because it doesn't explain *how* the keyword in question makes instance methods into class methods. It also doesn't explain what a 'more efficient singleton' is, or what `extend self` has to do with that.

Answer (score 30):

In a module, self is the module class itself.  So for example

```
puts self
```

will return Rake
so,

```
extend self
```

basically makes the instance methods defined in Rake available to it, so you can do

```
Rake.run_tests
```

Answer (score 26):

For me it always helps to think of `extend` as `include` inside the singleton class (also known as meta or eigen class).

You probably know that methods defined inside the singleton class are basically class methods:

```
module A
  class << self
    def x
      puts 'x'
    end
  end
end

A.x #=> 'x'
```

Now that we know that, `extend` will `include` the methods in the module inside the singleton class and thus expose them as class methods:

```
module A
  class << self
    include A

    def x
      puts 'x'
    end
  end

  def y
    puts 'y'
  end
end

A.x #=> 'x'
A.y #=> 'y'
```

Answer (score 17):

To avoid link rot, the [blog post of Chris Wanstrath](http://ozmm.org/posts/singin_singletons.html) linked by user83510 is reposted below (with his permission).
Still, nothing beats an original, so use his link for as long as it continues to work.

---

→ singin' singletons
18 November 2008
There’s stuff I just don’t understand. David Bowie, for instance. Or the Southern Hemisphere. But nothing quite boggles my mind like Ruby’s Singleton. Because really, it’s totally unnecessary.

Here’s what they want you to do with your code:

```
require 'net/http'

# first you setup your singleton
class Cheat
  include Singleton

  def initialize
    @host = 'http://cheat.errtheblog.com/'
    @http = Net::HTTP.start(URI.parse(@host).host)
  end


  def sheet(name)
    @http.get("/s/#{name}").body
  end
end

# then you use it
Cheat.instance.sheet 'migrations'
Cheat.instance.sheet 'yahoo_ceo'
```

But that’s crazy. Fight the power.

```
require 'net/http'

# here's how we roll
module Cheat
  extend self

  def host
    @host ||= 'http://cheat.errtheblog.com/'
  end

  def http
    @http ||= Net::HTTP.start(URI.parse(host).host)
  end

  def sheet(name)
    http.get("/s/#{name}").body
  end
end

# then you use it
Cheat.sheet 'migrations'
Cheat.sheet 'singletons'
```

Any why not? The API is more concise, the code is easier to test, mock, and stub, and it’s still dead simple to convert into a proper class should the need arise.

(( copyright ought ten chris wanstrath ))

Comment: Another way to avoid linkrot is to use something like the wayback machine -- http://web.archive.org -- it keeps a history of pages across the web, I've found it quite helpful in many cases of linkrot anyway.

Answer (score 4):

`extend self` includes all the existing instance methods as module methods. This is equivalent to saying `extend Rake`. Also `Rake` is an object of class `Module`.

Another way to achieve equivalent behavior will be:

```
module Rake
  include Test::Unit::Assertions

  def run_tests # etc.
  end

end 

Rake.extend(Rake)
```

This can be used to define self contained modules with private methods.

Answer (score 0):

https://benkoshy.github.io/2024/01/25/what-does-extend-self-mean-in-ruby.html

A faithful reproduction of the above is listed below:

This is best answered with a code example - which will hopefully make manifest the answer:

```rb
module Car
    extend self

    def drive
        puts "Don't stop me (driving)! I'm having such a good time, havin' a ball!"
    end

end

class Toyota
    include Car
end

t = Toyota.new
t.drive
# => Don't stop me (driving)! I'm having such a good time, havin' a ball!


Car.drive 
# => Don't stop me (driving)! I'm having such a good time, havin' a ball!
# extend self makes the above possible.

# Let's go one step further:
# Toyota.drive # will this work? What do you think?

class Toyota
    extend Car
end

Toyota.drive # now will it work?
```