# What does `extend self` mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I see some ruby modules that use `extend self` in the module definition. What does `extend self` mean here?

Comment: If the module is `A` you can of course instead write `extend A` within the module definition or `A.extend A` following the module definition.

Answer (score 4):

In that context `extend self` will make all instance methods available as class methods. For example, in this module:

```
module A
  def k
  end
  extend self
end
```

you can do `A.k`. This will also hold true: `A.instance_methods #=> [:k]; A.methods.include? :k #=> true` Look at [Ruby: extend self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733124/ruby-extend-self) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

It means to define its instance methods also as its class/module methods.