# Class extends self

Tags: php, oop

I stumbled across [this code](https://github.com/nicolas-grekas/Patchwork/blob/master/pieces/HTMLPurifier/class/FILTER.php) today

```
class FILTER extends self
{
    protected static function sanitizeHtml($html)
    {
        static $parser;

        if (!isset($parser)) $parser = new HTMLPurifier;

        return $parser->purify($html);
    }
}
```

What does this class gain from extending`self`? Im not quite sure if [this ruby example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733124/ruby-extend-self) is equivalent or even applicable to PHP.

Comment: That doesn't look valid. Have you tried it? It should produce an error.

Comment: Grabbed from a public github repository. Updated with link

Comment: It doesn't matter where you got it from. That would throw a fatal error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not valid code, wherever you saw it. It throws up an error.

> Fatal error: Cannot use 'self' as class name as it is reserved

You can see an example here: https://eval.in/775753